# How to Redirect to another Page in another solution in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The scenario is

- Project1
  webform1.aspx
- Project2
  webform2.aspx

On button click in webform1 it has to `Response.Redirect()` to the webform2.
I have added the reference assembly but could not figure out how to transfer.

If i write

> Response.Redirect("~/Webform2.aspx"); // the line will throw exception page not found

how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried removing tilde `~` sign and referred to fully qualified address of your other project. Like `Response.Redirect("/Project2/WebForm2.aspx")`;

Comment: see my explanation you will never confuse on this..

Answer (score 2):

Both projects will run as two different servers.

While development, they'd most commonly start with a `localhost` followed by a port number. Now your `Project1` isn't aware of `Project2`.

This means you'd have to manually provide the full url in the Response.Redirect call. Say your `Project2` is hosted at `http://localhost:4545`. The url of the 2nd web form would be `http://localhost:4545/Webform2.aspx`.

Therefore your response.redirect call would be

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:4545/Webform2.aspx");
```

So you'd have to manually hard-code it. Else you can think of making it dynamic via fetching this value from the configuration settings (web.config)

Comment: how to make it dynamic ? by adding a key and value ?

Comment: Yep. You figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

can you try to use Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx");

Comment: nops it has nothing to do with the scenario the ~ symbol will took it to the root

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you have added the reference assembly of Project2 in Project1 that you have added all the dlls of Projects2 in Project1, **but have you added the aspx files of project2 in project1???**

If not, then add those aspx files from Project2 to Project1 and then use your redirect code with the relative path as

```
Response.Redirect("~/Webform2.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

while saw your question i hope you need to get the difference between **Response.Redirect** and **Server.Transfer**

**Response.Redirect();**

Response.Redirect() is used when calling  the webpage present in another website i.e; which is not present in our current project.For example

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:1234/Webform2.aspx");
```

**Server.Transfer():**

Response.Redirect() is used when calling  the webpage present in current website i.e; which is present in our current project.For example

Response.Redirect("~/Webform2.aspx");

it will automatically fetches current project url loc and append it to the webpage.
i.e; `http://www.localhost:6789.com/Webform2.aspx`

**Example :**

*Project 1:*
webpage1.aspx

webpage2.aspx

*Project 2:*
webpage3.aspx

webpage4.aspx

Say you are in project1 if you redirect from  webpage1 to webpage2 use

Server.Transfer(~/webpage2.aspx)

If you want to redirect from webpage1 to webpage3 use

```
Response.redirect("http://localhost:1234/Webform2.aspx")
```

For more see : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJVjRUHXYbE